# Angular + Rails: Delete posts

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, angularjs, activerecord

I have an angular/rails app and I currently have the ability to post things, but I cannot seem to write the code required to delete posts.

My Github: https://github.com/JeremyLopez/ToDoList/tree/master/ToDoList

To create: (`tasks.js`)

```
angular.module('toDoList')
.factory('tasks', [
'$http',
function($http){

    var o = { 
        tasks: [] 
    };

    o.create = function(task) {
        return $http.post('/tasks.json', task).success(function(data){
            o.tasks.push(data);
        });
    };
```

but how would I write something very similar only deleting the post?  I have included my github since I am unsure which file is pertinent, but please focus on `app/controller/tasks_controller.rb`, `javascripts/home/mainCtrl.js`, and most importantly `javascripts/tasks/tasks.js`.

Thanks

Comment: where is `o` coming from?

Comment: @Daniel_L sorry about that.  I updated it

Comment: `$http.delete('/tasks/ + task.id + '.json')` ?

Comment: you can't return an async function. use a promise or a callback.

Comment: @charlespwd I tried that, and get a 404 error even though it is defined inthe routes

Comment: Can't know for sure, maybe it's without the `.json`. Are you using 
`:resources :tasks`?

Comment: @Daniel_L I'm new to angular and don't know what you mean by that comment.

Comment: @charlespwd yes I am `resources :tasks, only: [:create, :index, :show, :destroy]`

Comment: @charlespwd, I got it working, the error was in the controller!

Answer (score 0):

This function works!

```
o.destroy = function(task) {
        return $http.delete('/tasks/' + task.id + '.json').success(function(data){
            console.log("Task " + task.title + " has been deleted!")
        });
    };
```

...I did have to make changes to my `app/controllers/tasks_controller.rb`:

```
def destroy
        task = Task.find(params[:id])
        task.destroy

        respond_with task
  end
```